# Can we implement sound null safety in a project with non-null safety dependency used?

Tags: flutter, dart

My pubsec.yaml includes

dependencies used:

```
amazon_cognito_dependency_from_my_own_repo
other_null-safe_dependencies
```

Comment: you can migrate first to null-safety `amazon_cognito_dependency_from_my_own_repo` and then migrate your app if the only non null safe package is your own repository package.

Answer (score 0):

Sound null safety, by definition, relies on logic that only works if null safety is enabled everywhere. For mixed projects, you must disable it with the `--no-sound-null-safety` flag.

Comment: I did try to migrate it in mixed mode but the dependencies are not compatible with each other.